# How to access static files from a Spring Boot application, runned as a jar or war on WildFly

Tags: spring-boot, static, wildfly

In my Spring Boot application I have resources in the `resources` folder and these resources are accessible when application runs from my IDE. Here is the code:

```
dataDictionary.loadFieldDictionary(this.getClass().getResource("/rfdic/RDMFieldDictionary").getFile());
```

I know that packed into jar/war resources must be accessed not via path, but rather as a stream. The third-party library that I have to use does not support streams, only path as a string.
Is there a way to somehow simulate the presence of the resources in the filesystem when serving if from jar/war or they should be manualy placed somewhere in the filesystem with a reference from the app by the absolute path on the server?

Comment: If you want to load the resource from the root you have to use this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource

Comment: You mean this way I will be avble to refer to his resource via path?

Comment: Yes getClass().getResource searches relatively to the class

Comment: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getFile()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null

Comment: I see. What is dataDictionary

Comment: It's an object from the third-party lib. It can use only path, not stream and that is why I asked the question.

Comment: In that case you will not be able to read the files indeed because there is no path

Answer (score 0):

Deployment should be `Exploded` after deploy. In this case resources from war are accessible with the code from my question.